.NET: Web Authenticator not working on Sub Domain
In my MAUI application, I am using Web Authenticator to login with google. I am using .NET 8 asp.net core webapi project to handle it.
Application was working fine on the top domain https://example.com. Issue is occured when I moved the application to sub domain https://api.example.com.
Issue occur after we login into google account and the google redirects us to our application https://api.example.com/signin-google?.....

Error: api.example.com is currently unable to handle this request.


Code used in program.cs:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(o =>
{
    o.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
    .AddCookie()
    .AddGoogle(g =>
    {
        g.ClientId = GoogleClientId;
        g.ClientSecret = GoogleClientSecret;
        g.SaveTokens = true;   a.SaveTokens = true;
    });

Code used on Controller:
[HttpGet(ApiRoutes.MobileAuth.Google)]
public async Task Google()
{
    string scheme = "Google";
    var auth = await Request.HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(scheme);

    if (!auth.Succeeded
        || auth?.Principal == null
        || !auth.Principal.Identities.Any(id => id.IsAuthenticated)
        || string.IsNullOrEmpty(auth.Properties.GetTokenValue("access_token")))
    {
        await Request.HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(scheme);
    }
    else
    {
        var claims = auth.Principal.Identities.FirstOrDefault()?.Claims;
        string access_token = auth?.Properties?.GetTokenValue("access_token") ?? string.Empty;
        //other operations
        var url = callbackScheme + "://#access_token=" + (access_token.Trim());
        Request.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(url);
    }
}


The error 500 indicates that something went wrong on the web server while it was trying to process your request. You may try to set g.AuthorizationEndpoint in program.cs.

I have checked Authorization and Token Endpoint both are correct, I guess there might me some issue while returning to application

Yes, you can set the breakpoint and check which step went wrong. BTW, you can also refer to aspnet_google_auth_with_many_subdomains.

It is working fine on Localhost and main domain, issue occures only when i move application to subdomain

You can enable the  app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(); in your Program.cs to view detailed error messages
